# JQuery Datatables row height

Tags: jquery, html, datatables, html-table, dynamic-tables

I have a page where people can enter in first/last name, phone, email, and ethnicity click add and it adds an entry into the datatables. The problem is after clicking add the table shows up like this:

[image: Table]

How do I adjust the height of each row so that it shows up properly. This is my html code for the table:

```
<div id="table">
    <form id="add_nrow" title="Add">
        <br/>
        <label for="name">First Name</label><input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" class="required" rel="0" />
        <br />
        <label for="name">Last Name</label><input type="text" name="lname" id="lname" rel="1" />
        <br />
        <label for="name">Phone</label><input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" rel="3" />
        <br />
        <label for="name">Email</label><input type="text" name="email" id="email" rel="4" />
        <br />
        <label for="name">Ethnicity</label><input type="text" name="ethnicity" id="ethnicity" rel="5" />
        <br />   
        <input type="button" value="Add" id="addbtn" /><br/><br/>  
    </form>

    <table id="reg_more" border="1">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>First Name</th>
                <th>Last Name</th>
                <th>Phone</th>
                <th>Email</th>
                <th>Ethnicity</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my jquery code

```
$("#addbtn").click(addrow);
$('#reg_more').dataTable({
                "bLengthChange": false,
                "bInfo": false,
                "bPaginate": false,
                "bStateSave": true,
                "rowHeight": 'auto',
                "bFilter": true,
                "bSort": false,
                "bAutoWidth": false
            });


function addrow() {
    $('#reg_more').dataTable().fnAddData( [
        $('#fname').val(),
        $('#lname').val(),
        $('#phone').val(),
        $('#email').val(),
        $('#ethnicity').val()] );
    }
```

I have two questions really:

1. How do I adjust the height properly so the user can see the data?
2. If the enter in the information of 20 people, how do I take all that data so I can enter it into a mysql database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you can see in this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nicolapeluchetti/7Tm4t/3/) your code is correct and should work as expected.

In any case to set a row height, simply use css

```
 tr { height: 50px }
```

i think there is no need for it to be more complex.

Regarding the question on how to insert the data into a db, there are tons of examples on [google](https://www.google.it/#hl=it&sclient=psy-ab&q=basic+php+mysql+tutorial&oq=basic+php+mysql+tutorial&gs_l=hp.12...0.0.2.11211.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0...0.0...1c.svaVYOLGrvo&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d5b030dd275b5370&biw=1920&bih=955).

Comment: I tried setting the height of the row throw css like you said but that didn't work. I put:  `tr {
 height: 50px;
}` What am I doing wrong? If it works in fiddle is it something to do with page height maybe?

Comment: @Richard did you set it as the last statement of the last CSS file you import?Otherwise it's being overridden :)

Answer (score 2):

This is an old question, but if like me you don't want to do this in CSS you can use [drawCallback](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) in 1.10 or higher to alter the table cell padding and/or height using JS.

```
var import_list = $( 'table.import_list' ).DataTable( {
    'drawCallback': function () {
        $( 'table.import_list tbody tr td' ).css( 'padding', '5px 8px 5px 8px' );
    }
} )
```