# Datatables limit row height

Tags: css, datatables

This seems like a simple problem, but I can't seem to work it out.

I have a Datatables table, and one of the elements contains a free-form text field.  When displayed in the table, I want this to only display the first line of this text field, rather than all of it.

I've created a jsfiddle here:  [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc9L5osp/)

And an example picture showing what I'm trying to achieve:  [Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdEjC.png)

I've tried to set the height of the `<td>` as below, but this doesn't work.

```
height:     20px !important;
min-height: 20px !important;
max-height: 20px !important;
```

It works for expanding the cells larger (eg: 80px), but not smaller...

I also tried this: [JQuery Datatables row height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444423/jquery-datatables-row-height)  but no joy.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think using JS will be the best approach here.

Comment: @fjellfly I'm happy for the solution not to involve CSS, that was just my (perhaps naive) attempt to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works when you put a block element inside your `td`, for example a `div`. See the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pc9L5osp/9/) for the working code. If you only want to limit bigger cells you should then use `max-height` in your CSS.

```
            <tr>
                <td>Brazil</td>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        500
                        <br>500
                        <br>500
                        <br>
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td>200</td>
            </tr>
```

Comment: Thanks.  If I load the data into my table using an AJAX call, though, then I think I would need to do some extra fiddling (http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2025/fnrowcallback-and-fnupdate) in order to wrap it in a <div> when loading the data.  Is there another alternative?

Comment: I don't think so, but there may be some I can't think of.