# How to change <TR> element height via CSS?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I'm trying to change tr height of my jquery datatable, I'm looking for a property to set in the `.DataTable`, but unfortunately I doesn't find nothing.

So I though to set the height of tr like this:

```
$('#datatable')
        .css('min-height', '650px')
        .css('tr height', '20px')
        .DataTable
```

unfortunately the tr height isn't changed. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: If I'm understanding your question correctly, you'll need to access the child tr element of the table directly and then set the css. .children('tr').css('height','20px')

Comment: 'tr height' is not valid css

Comment: Why you don't change in CSS?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery Datatables row height](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12444423/jquery-datatables-row-height)

Comment: @MadalinaTaina Not really a duplicate, as the post you're linking to was a bug of low row height and the answer is CSS Styling, not programmatically changing the row height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you are looking to just change the height of tr in table hen you should use this

```
$('#tableID tr').css('height', '200px')
```

or if you want to just increase the height of the tbody element then you can do this by

```
$('#tableID tbody tr').css('height', '20px')
```

Only header :

```
$('#tableID thead tr').css('height', '20px')
```

Comment: This is the correct answer ! Don't get lost with _.children()_ etc


https://jsfiddle.net/c02b4hxv/2/ for the sake of example

Comment: @GrégoireFruleux is possible set also the min height of a table? 'cause I actually seems cannot have both set: `$("#datatable").css("min-height", "650px");` How can I do that?

Comment: @user3287550 I guess it is useless, check this [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11275916/6341631) , it says that _min-height_ and _height_ are the same for tables ...